# Short array syntax in PHP 5.6 doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays

What could be the reason this code doesn't work in PHP 5.6.23?

```
$change_text = [
    "ok" => "Użytkownik zmieniony poprawnie.",
    "new" => "Użytkownik dodany poprawnie.",
    "delete" => "Użytkownik został usunięty.",
];
```

Works on my server with 5.6 and I've tested it on some other servers and it's fine. I moved a site to a new server and it has PHP 5.6.23 but this does't work...

Also the PHP documentation says:

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

The error i get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't work __how__? Do you get error? Are you sure about php version on server?

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure that the line number in `....` is this line number?

Comment: @DariuszPietrala  Is `Array()`  working fine?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. I don't have access to php.ini and the guy I talked to said that it's only 5.4 feature and I need to change the code... I need higher version for some of the features, but I don't want to change the code.

Comment: @beginner Yes, working fine.

Comment: There is no reason I can see why this wouldn't work. run `var_dump(phpversion())` and confirm they're telling you the right thing. Otherwise, the issue is further up in the code, or this code isn't where the error message is telling you.

Comment: Or you may have any syntax error , check the code again carefully

Comment: @JonStirling I know this is really weird. The `var_dump(phpversion())` says `string(6) "5.6.23"`, the phpinfo says 5.6.23. The file was copied from another server with 5.6 and it works fine there.

Comment: @DariuszPietrala Then the error is somewhere else. More debugging required :)

Comment: But if the error is somewhere else why does `array(...)` work?

Comment: @DariuszPietrala Try to `print_r()` a  small array, `print_r([1,2,3]);`Check if this is working?

Comment: Thanks @beginner. Yeah, thought about it already. I did this `<?php var_dump(["ok" => "Użytkownik zmieniony poprawnie.","new" => "Użytkownik dodany poprawnie.","delete" => "Użytkownik został usunięty.",]); ?>` so basically the same array and it works. The file I had problem with had few arrays like `$arr = [...];` and when I changed them all to `array()` all works fine. I have no idea why ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure the problem is old version of php. I had the same problem. I ran simple script with phpinfo() from browser and saw, that version is 5.6, but problem was in cli. So I checked version in cli, and It was 5.3! Thats it. ))